# 'Transaction nonce is too low. Try incrementing the nonce.' while following truffle tutorial

Tags: truffle, nonce, kovan

I ran into a nonce error on the last leg of this tutorial : https://www.trufflesuite.com/boxes/flashloan-box

I also supplemented the tutorial with this video on yt(fyi b/c some of the code comes from there as well) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYSGeVkCWXU&t=1s

*note that I funded the contract prior

```
truffle(kovan)> amount = web3.utils.toWei('1000')
'1000000000000000000000'
```

set the asset variable to the txn hash of the curreny DAI coin

```
truffle(kovan)> asset = '0xFf795577d9AC8bD7D90Ee22b6C1703490b6512FD'
```

Everything was going stellar until I tried to execute the flashloan itself:

```
truffle(kovan)> f.flashloan(asset, amount)
Uncaught:
{
  code: -32010,
  message: 'Transaction nonce is too low. Try incrementing the nonce.'
}
truffle(kovan)>
```

How should I address the nonce issue? I read in some post from 2020 that there was an advanced user option in the works to manipulate it, but I didn't find any follow up on that.

Thank you for your time

*Edit
I updated the migration file and then forked a branch from the main net using the following command:
ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_KEY -i 1

This solves the primary issue of this thread so I will close it

Comment: How are you connecting to kovan? Perhaps through Infura.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Yes, I am using infura. I tried using the >> ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_KEY -i 1  and updated my migration files just to be certain, but now I can't find a RESERVE_ADDRESS that will work with my flashloan call

Answer (score 2):

updated the migration file and then forked a branch from the main net using the following command:

```
ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_KEY -i 1
```

This fixed the primary issue of this thread